# The "closed" review queue is zero

Tags: discussion, review, reviewing

This seems unusual in that the number of posts to review is generally at least 100.  Just wondering if there were any trends on SF that might be applicable?  Is the posting volume down?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/354458/user-posts-per-week Shows no real change in posts per week.

Comment: I was thinking also that there might be fewer reviewers taking the time and effort to identify problematic posts.

Answer (score 5):

There are currently 38 questions in the close queue. If you have already voted on or skipped them, they do not show for you.

Comment: The implication of my post is either (1) there are fewer posts than usual....OR (2) there are fewer people actively reviewing posts thus fewer entries OR (3) there are many more people reviewing posts. I was thinking the reason was (1).....maybe (3)?

Comment: The _number_ of questions in the close queue doesn't seem to be unusual.